# Why do we need continuity for the convergence of the localized martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times, local-martingales

$M(t)$ is a local continuous martingale and $\tau_{k}$ is a localizing sequence $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}M(t\wedge \tau_{n})=M(t)$.
I know that this is true for continuous martingales, but why do we need the continuity here. Does it not work without continuity ?

Comment: You don't need continuity. For $N(\omega)$ large enough but finite, we have $t \wedge \tau_n(\omega)  = t$ for all $n \geq N(\omega)$.  Thus, $\lim_n M(t\wedge \tau_n ) = M(t) a.s.$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_martingale for example where they make no such assumptions.